Doctype error when upload image to product
This is a strange error on my prestashop 1.7.8.11
And it´s the first time i see it, its happend when i uppload a product image.
I have tryed to change the rights, with no luck.
4.jpg: 
&lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt;
&lt;html&gt;
  &lt;head&gt;
    &lt;meta charset="UTF-8" /&gt;
    &lt;title&gt;  Oops... looks like an unexpected error occurred.
&lt;/title&gt;
      &lt;link rel="stylesheet" href="/pshop2com/admin123/themes/new-theme/public/theme.css?1.7.8.11" /&gt;
    &lt;link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/pshop2com/admin123/favicon.ico?1.7.8.11" /&gt;
  &lt;/head&gt;
  &lt;body&gt;
      &lt;div class="container"&gt;
    &lt;div class="row mt-5"&gt;
      &lt;div class="col"&gt;
        &lt;div class="card"&gt;
          &lt;div class="card-body text-center"&gt;
            &lt;img class="img-responsive"
                 src="/pshop2com/admin123/themes/new-theme/img/error/500.svg?1.7.8.11"
                 alt="Oops... looks like an unexpected error occurred."
            &gt;

            &lt;div class="mt-3"&gt;
              &lt;p class="error-header"&gt;
                Oops... looks like an unexpected error occurred.
              &lt;/p&gt;

                              &lt;div class="mx-auto"&gt;
                  &lt;p class="mb-0"&gt;The file &amp;quot;/tmp/phpxd3vhx&amp;quot; does not exist&lt;/p&gt;
                  &lt;p class="mb-0"&gt;[Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\Exception\FileNotFoundException 0]&lt;/p&gt;
                &lt;/div&gt;
              
              &lt;div class="mt-4"&gt;
                &lt;form action="/pshop2com/admin123/index.php/errors/enable-debug-mode?_token=pR87ZN9-wQNaDK5DqnEK1GT3C0QGK4PtX-f0p_LN-Zg" method="post" class="d-inline"&gt;
                  &lt;input type="hidden" name="_redirect_url" value="/pshop2com/admin123/index.php/sell/catalog/products/image/upload/27224?_token=pR87ZN9-wQNaDK5DqnEK1GT3C0QGK4PtX-f0p_LN-Zg"&gt;

                  &lt;button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="submit"&gt;
                    Enable debug mode
                  &lt;/button&gt;
                &lt;/form&gt;
                &lt;button class="btn btn-primary js-go-back-btn ml-3" type="button"&gt;
                  Back to previous page
                &lt;/button&gt;
              &lt;/div&gt;

              &lt;p class="mt-3"&gt;
                &lt;a href="https://docs.prestashop-project.org/1.7-documentation/user-guide/configuring-shop/advanced-parameters/performance#performance-debugmode" target="_blank"&gt;
                  Learn more about debug mode
                  &lt;i class="material-icons"&gt;arrow_right_alt&lt;/i&gt;
                &lt;/a&gt;
              &lt;/p&gt;
            &lt;/div&gt;
          &lt;/div&gt;
        &lt;/div&gt;
      &lt;/div&gt;
    &lt;/div&gt;
  &lt;/div&gt;
      &lt;script src="/pshop2com/admin123/themes/new-theme/public/error.bundle.js?1.7.8.11"&gt;&lt;/script&gt;
  &lt;/body&gt;
&lt;/html&gt;


And im really stuck right now.
Prestashop version 1.7.8.11
php version 7.3

Check this , it's a bug from ps_eventbus module, there's an update already: https://github.com/PrestaShopCorp/ps_eventbus/issues/330
